# Local domain for server IP without hosts file

Tags: linux, networking, domain, local-area-network

I have configured a LEMP stack on my server running 2 applications:

```
x.x.x.x/app1 
x.x.x.x/app2
```

How can I setup multiple domains in my LAN without having to change every clients hosts file? Like this:

```
app1.local  
app2.local
```

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Install DNS server (bind, may be), set up it as root of your domain names (app1.local, app2.local) and use it as your clients dns server.

Answer (score -1):

You simply set the DNS entry for both domains to point to the same server, then in nginx you can configure multiple server blocks:

```
  server {
    server_name app1.local;
    access_log logs/app1.access.log main;

    root /var/www/app1;
  }

  server {
    server_name app2.local;
    access_log  logs/app2.access.log main;

    root /var/www/app2;
  }
}
```

Within an HTTP GET request, clients usually sent the `Host` header, so a webserver can return different sites depending on which host the client wanted to see.

Comment: He did ask, how to set up a DNS-server, not how to create a virtualhost

Comment: @Orphans he wanted app1.local to point to x.x.x.x/app1 and app2.local to x.x.x.x/app2. This is not possible with DNS alone.